# Complexity of An Algorithm(Nested loops)

Tags: java, c, algorithm, time-complexity, discrete-mathematics

I'm given code for an algorithm as such:

```
1  sum =0;
2    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
3      for(j=1; j<= n; j*=3)
4        sum++;
```

I'm told this algorithm runs in `O(nlogn)` where log is in base 3.
So I get that the second line runs `n times`, and since line 3 is independent of line 2 I would have to multiply the two to get the Big O, however, I'm not sure how the answer is nlogn(log in base 3), is their a guaranteed way to figure this out everytime?  It seems like with nested loops, there's a different case that can occur each time.

Comment: The O() runtime of the second loop, on its own, runs exactly (1/3) * n times, right? So this is better than O(n), but obviously constant, so we use log as an upper bound because it is in between.

Comment: with time complexity the base of the logarithm is of no relevance, thus it is eluded and simply `O(log n)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have been told is correct. The algorithm runs in `O(nlog(n))`. The third line: `for(j=1; j<= n; j*=3)` runs in `O(log3(n))` because you multiply by 3 each time. To see it more clearly solve the problem: how many times you need to multiply 1 by 3 to get n. Or `3^x = n`. The solution `is x = log3(n)`

Comment: Please stop writing constants inside Big O notation, it describes the speed of function's growth in relation to input parameter(s), not estimated execution time.

Comment: @user3707125 where do you see constants? I wrote about log3 because the OP explicitly asked where log3 came from.

Comment: here: "runs in `O(log3(n))`", it would be more correct to say "runs approximately log3(n) times, which results in asymptotic complexity of O(log(n))".

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Algo runs in nlog(n) times where log is base 3.

The easiest way to calculate complexity is to calculate number of operations done.

The outer for loop runs n times. And let's calculate how many times each inner for loop runs for each n. So for n=1,2, inner for loop runs 1 times.  For n=3,4,5,6,7,8 inner for loop runs 2 times. And so on...

That means that the inner for loop runs in logarithmic time (log(n)) for each n.

So n*log(n) will be total complexity.

Answer (score 0):

On the second loop you have `j *= 3`, that means you can divide n by 3 log3(n) times. That gives you the O(logn) complexity.
Since your first loop has a O(n) you have O(nlogn) in the end